# Not able to execute join operation in HIVE using Coudera QuickStart VM

Tags: hive

Hive error when trying to execute join operation on Cloudera QuickStart

Can you please give an Idea , why this error occurred

```
hive> desc orders;
OK
order_id                int                                         
order_date              string                                      
order_customer_id       int                                         
order_status            string                                      
Time taken: 0.318 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)

hive> desc order_items;
OK
order_item_id           int                                         
order_item_order_id     int                                         
order_item_product_id   int                                         
order_item_quantity     tinyint                                     
order_item_subtotal     double                                      
order_item_product_price    double                                      
Time taken: 0.325 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)

hive> select order_date, sum(order_item_subtotal) daily_revenue 
      from orders 
      join order_items on order_id = order_item_order_id
      group by order_date;
```

> Query ID = cloudera_20180323171616_557f9c3a-2443-42ec-b509-13a7d7f680d0
>   Total jobs = 1
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

hive> 
//I have tried with new database and by reloading tables before executing this query but I get same error every time.

Thanks in Advance for your kind consideration.

Comment: nothing wrong with the query. use aliases before column names and try again.

Answer (score 0):

> select o.order_date, sum(oi.order_item_subtotal) as daily_revenue from
>   orders o join order_items oi on o.order_id = oi.order_item_order_id
>   group by o.order_date;

This should solve your problem.